# pass diferent parameters to a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working with documents, trying to create a docx via a web page, basicly i say i want a table, a paragraph and it should append to my doc, at the backgroud i have a function that deals witht that stuff this way:

```
public void CreateDoc(params object[] document)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

        new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);

        Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

        foreach (var docSections in document)
        {
           body.Append(new Paragraph(new ParagraphProperties(),
           new Run((Run)docSections)));
        }

    }
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(DOCUMENTSLOCATION));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Files/test5.docx"), stream.ToArray());



  }
```

watch out the parameters received in the CreateDoc, it can receive a unlimited number of paramters inside the object, that is what i want since i don'tn know how much sections my doc will have (tables, paragraphs, images etc..)-

My problem is that i need t pass more parameters that are not directly related to the construction of the file, like for example: name of the file. My idea was to pass it as the second parameter in the CreateDoc function, but how can i pass it from the other side?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass specific parameters to function if you have defined them as such. For instance, if you are certain that you'll always need `filename` as a parameter while calling this function, you can modify the function parameter as such:

```
public void CreateDoc(string filename, params object[] document)
{
   ...
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
CreateDoc("filename.docx", <param1>, <param2>);
```

Comment: so, can i pass just a array of objects as a second parameter?

Comment: Yes, and you wouldn't need the `params` keyword if you did it like that.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that.. You could have `params object` and pass in as many parameters you want, or have `object[]` and pass in an array of objects.

Comment: you know how it works internaly? because 1 thing is confusing to me, since i am passing a random number of parameters, how it knows that 1 is the filename and the other are part of the object array?

Comment: Since you have defined the first parameter to be a string, the compiler looks for the first parameter in the method call - which it expects to be a string. Any number of parameters after that would be given to the `params` - again by matching the parameter type. You would be able to find some documentation on MSDN's C# language reference.

Answer (score 0):

### For First Step:

You Can pass Data with `your own Structure` instead `Object`.
Like `Data Type` and `Data Content`

### And Second Step:

Check `DataType` of Parameter and then Manage it